# node.js watchFile() not watching

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have written this small code to watch the *config.json* file but when I run the file

```
node watch.js
```

and change the values in config.json file values nothing changes no updated file is shown on the cmd, cmd somewhat freezes.

```
var fs = require("fs");

console.log("Started");

var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./files/config.json"));

console.log("Initial config: ", config);  

fs.watchFile(".files/config.json", function(current, previous){  

    cconsole.log("Config Changed");  
    config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./files/config.json"));  
    console.log("New Config file: ", config);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `fs.watchFile`, you are telling it to watch ".files" and it should be "./files".

Also as a shortcut, if you are using JSON, you can just do:

```
var config = require("./files/config.json");
```

and your JSON will be parsed into an object stored in `config`